# Hiearchical Beta-Binomial model via rjags: How to draw posterior sample/do inference on posterior exactly?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian, jags, bugs

I have the following code for bugs model which I want to use with rjags:

```
model {
for (i in 1:N_std) {
# binomial likelihood
y[i] ~ dbin(p[i], n[i])
logit(p[i])  <-  logit_p[i]
logit_p[i]   ~  dnorm(mu, inv_tau2)  
}

inv_tau2 <- pow(tau, -2)
tau ~ dnorm(0, prior_prec_tau)I(0,) # HN(scale = 1 / sqrt(prior_prec_tau))
mu  ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)

logit_p.pred     ~  dnorm(mu, inv_tau2)
p.pred <- 1 / (1 + exp(-logit_p.pred))
}
```

I was wondering, why the predeiction part (the last two lines of the model) are needed. Why is it not just possible, to draw posterior samples from p via

```
 help_mcmc_samples <- coda.samples(fit, "p", n.iter = 5000)
```

I tried both, directly drawing p.pred via

```
help_mcmc_samples <- coda.samples(fit, "p.pred", n.iter = 5000)
```

and the approach above.

I compared the drawn values and realized, that the mean is similar, but the variance in the second, drawing samples of p.pred from the model, A LOT LARGER. Below you can see Boxplots of the drawn samples. On the left, when drawing samples of p.pred. On the right, when drawing samples of p.

Can someone help? What is the difference?

Would be great. Many thanks in advance!

[image: Box plot of drawn samples]